# How to not redirect if images are located in specific subdirectory with nginx?

Tags: nginx

I current;y have configured to redirect if a user tries to direct access images by browser for all images but I don't want them redirected if the images are located in a specific subdirectory which is `/static/favicon/`

```
    location ~* ^/(?<filenum>.*)\.(jpeg|jpg|png|webp)$ {
    proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7492;
    valid_referers example.com;
    if ($invalid_referer = "1") {
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
    return 301 https://example.com/$filenum; 
}
    }
```

How can I not make it redirect if the images are located in `/static/favicon/`

Comment: What do you mean by *not redirect*? Not `proxy_pass` or not `return 301`?

Comment: @RichardSmith I don't want `return 301` if image is located in `/static/favicon/`